# Why won't my domain records display even after several hours?

Tags: networking, dns, domain, dig

I updated my domain records to add CNAME records and a TXT record, but even after several days I cannot see them when I query the domain.

Screenshot of domain records:

[image]

Query results:

```
$ dig @dns1.name-services.com kizbit.com any

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1 <<>> @dns1.name-services.com kizbit.com any
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 37571
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 10, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 5
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;kizbit.com.                    IN      ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
kizbit.com.             3600    IN      NS      dns5.name-services.com.
kizbit.com.             1800    IN      AAAA    2607:f878:5:9::b5d1:cb0f
kizbit.com.             1800    IN      SOA     dns1.name-services.com. info.name-services.com. 2002050701 10800 3600 604800 3600
kizbit.com.             1800    IN      TXT     "v=spf1 a ip4:184.82.92.84 ip4:192.185.179.138 include:_spf.spamarrest.com"
kizbit.com.             3600    IN      NS      dns4.name-services.com.
kizbit.com.             1800    IN      A       184.82.92.84
kizbit.com.             3600    IN      NS      dns1.name-services.com.
kizbit.com.             1800    IN      MX      10 kizbit.com.
kizbit.com.             3600    IN      NS      dns3.name-services.com.
kizbit.com.             3600    IN      NS      dns2.name-services.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
dns2.name-services.com. 300     IN      A       98.124.197.1
dns5.name-services.com. 300     IN      A       98.124.196.1
dns4.name-services.com. 300     IN      A       98.124.194.1
dns3.name-services.com. 300     IN      A       98.124.193.1
dns1.name-services.com. 300     IN      A       98.124.192.1

;; Query time: 89 msec
;; SERVER: 98.124.192.1#53(98.124.192.1)
;; WHEN: Mon May 19 00:53:09 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 404
```

I also tried without @dns1.name-services.com, and I also tried `nslookup`, but neither showed the extra CNAME records. I tried to contact ENom, but they directed me to my reseller. My reseller gave a vague "if you are using our servers, the changes happen without any delay whatsoever, as long as you click to save them" response.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about domain registration, which isn't within the scope of this site. This question is probably better suited for [webmasters.se](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), you should flag it for moderator attention and ask that they migrate it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I didn't know how `dig` works, and you have to query the actual sub-domain to get any information. I thought everything would appear as it did in the online form if you just look at the root domain!

```
$ dig @dns1.name-services.com _amazonses.kizbit.com any

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_amazonses.kizbit.com.  1799    IN      TXT     "C9DR1H5StZrI97xjWjkVcd/2jwW9R05MBr49T8IyooI="
_amazonses.kizbit.com.  1799    IN      SOA     dns1.name-services.com. info.name-services.com. 2002050701 10800 3600 604800 3600
```

Comment: There can be hundreds of CNAMEs from numerous domains pointed at a single A record.  No query on one record could be expected to bring up all associated CNAMEs pointing to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's there....

```
[Nevins-Mac-mini:~] nevin% host www.kizbit.com
www.kizbit.com is an alias for kizbit.com.
kizbit.com has address 184.82.92.84
kizbit.com has IPv6 address 2607:f878:5:9::b5d1:cb0f
kizbit.com mail is handled by 10 kizbit.com.
```

A CNAME has pointers to A-records, but A-records do not have pointers to CNAMEs.

Comment: What about the the Amazon DKIM CNAMEs? I don't see those!